# Get data from sqlite on android

Tags: java, sqlite

I an trying to fetch data from my SQLite database on Android. However, when I run the code and see the Android Monitor, I get this message:

> 04-14 15:27:27.737 11177-11177/com.example.daniel.toto E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 6 rows, 5 columns.

This is the method in the database helper class I use to get the data from the database:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllSales() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res;
    res = db.rawQuery( "select * from sales", null );
    if (res != null) {
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SALES_TABLE_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    } else {
        array_list = null;
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

This is where I call it in onCreate method the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales);
    mydb = new SalesDBHelper(this.getBaseContext());
    array_list = mydb.getAllSales();
}
```

Comment: `SALES_TABLE_NAME ` sounds like a table name not a column's name. In the error message `column -1` means there is no column with the name you're trying to get. `res.getColumnIndex(SALES_TABLE_NAME)` returns `-1`

Comment: thanks !  i figured it out, but is there any other way to get data?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get data" but you could use a more explicit query like `select salesID from sales` and then access the value of the `salesID` column using its index `res.getString(0)`.

Comment: this is not how I code.  while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {  I code this as while (! res.isAfterLast())  it will get easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: I tried it , and worked fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for deciphering the error message. Indeed the part of the error message `column -1`means: there is no such column.
Thank you a lot for pointing it out, it finally solved my problem!